# UITableViewRowAction action is triggered on swipe instead on tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

I am not sure i understood it correctly, the documentation is a bit confusing here, but given the following code in the body of a UITableView delegate:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let action = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowAction.Style.normal,
                                          title: "Do Something!") { (_, indexPath) in
                                            self.doSomething()
                                            }
        return [action]
    }
```

the call to `doSomething()` method is performed **in simulator** on completion of the swipe-to-left action beside on tap on the "Do Something!" button. 
I don't want the call to be performed twice. Is there something wrong with my configuration or i have not understood the purpose of `UITableViewRowAction`?

TLDR: i want swipe action callback to be triggered **only** when the button that appears is tapped.

Thank you.

Comment: You probably want to use the iOS 11+ style methods. See trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt. The editActionsForRow is the older way. Then you can use:     let swipeAction = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
    swipeAction.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false // This is the line which disables full swipe
    return swipeAction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prevent this behavior you need an implementation of new iOS.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
let myAction = UIContextualAction(style: .someStyle, title: "Some tilte") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
    print("action has been triggered")
    completionHandler(true)
}
let preventSwipeFullAction = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [myAction ])
preventSwipeFullAction .performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false // set false to disable full swipe action
return preventSwipeFullAction 
}
```

[TableView Trailing Swipe Action](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/2902367-tableview)

Remember `tableView.isEditing` need to be `false` to allow `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` be called.

> `completionHandler(true)` // passing true enable handler call action